# JavaScript to match random number and text input

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, random, innerhtml

I'm trying to make a really basic anti-spam function where the script generates a random number and then the user has to type it in a text field in order for the form to validate. My problem is grabbing the value of the generated number to match it against the input. Here is how I generate the random number:

```
window.onload=function randomNumberGenerator()
  {
    var x=document.getElementById("number");
    var randomNumber=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    x.innerHTML=randomNumber;
            }
```

I was trying to get the number at validation like this:

```
var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["realPerson"].value;
var correct=document.getElementById("number").value;

if (x != correct)
  {
  alert("Please write in the correct number");
  return false;
  }
```

But after a while i realized that innerHTML doesn't put anything in the DOM that can be read (as least that seems to be the deal). So how can I retrieve that number to compare it when the form is submitted? I have thought about using a cookie, but that seemed a bit intimidating...

Thank you!

Comment: Plz show the html. what type of field is 'number'. Will var correct=document.getElementById("number").innerHTML; works for you??

Comment: Why not use [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha "reCAPTCHA: Stop Spam, Read Books")? Lazy programmers are the best programmers: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/how-to-be-lazy-dumb-and-successful.html

Comment: @user2073143 - Where is the HTML? Put it in your question please.

Comment: It's just that i have a very limited amount of space to work with.

Answer (score 2):

If you can access the generated number from client side, I think you lose the purpose. Better generate the random number in the server side and validate it after form submission .

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately I don't have access to the submission server. This form goes to a CRM!  But you gave me an idea: I can generate the random number with php and echo it out and then grab it using javascript.

Comment: Also, for better protection, LEAVE the generated number on serverside and check the input there.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to just use innerHTML a second time, perhaps with a parseInt

```
var correct=parseInt(document.getElementById("number").innerHTML);
```

Comment: Shouldn't really make a difference as the OP is not using strict inequality to compare `x` and `correct`, but +1 for pointing it out.

Comment: @user2073143 - If you want to put html in a comment, surround it with ` marks.

Comment: Thank you Travis. That did it. Unfortunately i don't have the reputation to up vote you...

Comment: @user2073143 - You can always accept this answer as correct :D